# Passing a generic template parameter from a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, generics, invoke

*I am coming from c# so please excuse anything I may get wrong in trying to ask this question.*

I have created a map that contains a string and a method to handle invoking a method by a string:

```
//MyClass.h
void SerializeCustomData();
std::unordered_map<std::string, void(MyClass::*)()> functionMap;

MyMethod() {
    functionMap["SerializeCustomData"] = &MyClass::SerializeCustomData;
};
```

**My question is**; how can I have my map take in a parameter for the method? Either a generic type or a string in c++?

*Example:*

```
SerializeCustomData(std::string);
```

Comment: I recommend using `std::function` instead of member function pointers in general.

Comment: Are you looking for a container for these parameters? I you are, try using std::function and std::bind.

Comment: @mileniumbug thanks, so off the top of my head it would  look like this: 
`std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void(std::string)> > functionMap;`

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear: how do you intend to call the functions from a map? Are you binding to the instances of `MyClass` or do you intend to call the function on them?

Comment: @milleniumbug, currently this is how I am my functions from the map: 
`if (functionMap.find(CommandArgument) != functionMap.end())
   (this->*(functionMap[CommandArgument]))();`

My question could be unclear seeing how I don't know how I intend to call the function any other way, especially with parameters... Kind of the chicken before the egg deal we have here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class MyClass
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void(MyClass&, std::string)>> functionMap;
public:
    void MyMethod()
    {
        functionMap.emplace("SerializeCustomData", &MyClass::SerializeCustomData);
    }

    void CallSerialize()
    {
        functionMap.at("SerializeCustomData")(*this, "argument");
    }

    void SerializeCustomData(std::string s)
    {
        std::cout << "hello: " << s << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass c;
    c.MyMethod();
    c.CallSerialize();
}
```

Here the function from the map is called with a `MyClass&` argument and a string. Note that the `MyClass` isn't bound to the callback, and so we're passing it explicitly.